# How can I manage to redirect each request to https://url.com/#/foo

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I used Vue-Router for my webapp and every route has to follow this pattern :
https://myapp/#/foo

I wanted to know if there was a htaccess rule to redirect each https://myapp/foo to https://myapp/#/foo.

So yeah I could make redirection for each of my Vue Route pattern but it wouldn't be optimal. Any thoughts guys ?

Answer (score 0):

Go into your

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/

and edit your `000-default.conf`

Inside `<VirtualHost *:80>` add the following:

```html
Redirect permanent /foo https://myapp/#/foo
```

your whole `000-default.conf` should then look like this:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # other stuff
    Redirect permanent /foo https://myapp/#/foo
    # other stuff
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart your `apache2`:

> service apache2 restart

Now your site should redirect everything that starts with `/foo` to `https://myapp/#/foo`

Comment: Unfortunately, my hosting doesn't allow me to edit this file :( Is there a way to achieve it with .htaccess file ? Thank you for your answer !